# Tkinter: añadir background image en frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, interfaz-gráfica

Trato de crear un background de imagen en un `Frame` basándome en las respuestas a esta [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54250448/tkinter-background-image-in-frame).

El bg-img se crea sin problemas, la imagen aparece y funciona como fondo, el problema reside en que los widgets no aparecen.

Entre los comentarios de la respuesta antes referida la persona no cree que se pueda hacer esto en un `Frame` y en cambio lo realiza en un `Canvas`, pregunto como `Frame` en caso de que alguno sepa algo mas que el:)

## ¿Qué he intentando?

1. Agregar la porción de código del bg-img en el inicializador, tenia la idea de que así es como se aplicaría a todos los `frames`.
2. Modificar `self.canva` para que en lugar de un `Canvas` fuera un `Frame`, seguía apareciendo el fondo pero sin los widgets.
3. Modificar la clase `PaginaGeneral` para que en lugar de que pasara como argumento la creación de un `Frame` fuera un `Canvas` (así es como lo deje en el ejemplo)
4. Modificar el `place` pensé que quizá residía un problema a la hora de acomodar los widgets, lo cambie por `pack` pero tampoco funciono, aparecía una porción en blanco arriba de los widgets solamente.
5. Tratar de comprender y aplicar los visto [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10158552/how-to-use-an-image-for-the-background-in-tkinter), [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41208246/tkinter-custom-background-image) y [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10158552/how-to-use-an-image-for-the-background-in-tkinter). Los problemas que encontré es que no estoy usando la librería PIL y no entendiendo muy bien algunas cosas que hacen con ella, lo otro es que utilizaban otras clases que no supe aplicar muy bien a las que ya tengo creadas.

Ejemplo del codigo:

```
class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self._frame = None
        self.switch_frame(PaginaGeneral)

    def switch_frame(self, frame_class):
        new_frame = frame_class(self)
        if self._frame is not None:
            self._frame.destroy()
        
        self.canva = tk.Canvas(self)
        self.imagen = PhotoImage(file = "fondo.png")
        self.fondo_label = tk.Label(self, image= self.imagen)
        self.fondo_label.img = self.imagen
        self.fondo_label.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor='center')
        
        self._frame = new_frame
        self._frame.place()

class PaginaGeneral(tk.Canvas):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Canvas.__init__(self, master)
        tituloPrograma= tk.Label(self, 
                                 text= "EJEMPLO")
        tituloPrograma.config(fg="black", 
                              bg="blue", 
                              font=("Verdana", 15))
        tituloPrograma.grid()

        botonSiguienteGeneral= tk.Button(self, 
                                         text= "INICIO")
        botonSiguienteGeneral.grid(row= 6, column=0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

Eternamente agradecido por su orientación.

Comment: +1 por una pregunta bien detallada c:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mi me ha funcionado sin necesidad del canvas, el uso de Pillow es sencillo y tiene un comando que se llama ImageTk que convierte la imagen en el tipo de imagen para Tkinter.

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

ventana = tk.Tk()
largo = 300
alto = 300

ventana.geometry(str(largo)+"x"+str(alto))


img = Image.open("imagen.jpeg")
img = img.resize((largo,alto))   
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
fondo_label = tk.Label(ventana, image= img)
fondo_label.place(bordermode=tk.INSIDE)
```

Agrego dos botones para probar que aparecen encima de la imagen:

```
btn = tk.Button(ventana, text="boton 1")
btn.grid(row=0,column=0)

btn1 = tk.Button(ventana, text="boton 2")
btn1.grid(row=1,column=0)

ventana.mainloop()
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! El objetivo es intentar lograrlo sin usar PIL pero visto las complicaciones lo estudiare para implementarlo. Si es la única solución viable no hay de otra...

Comment: En realidad PIL solo lo he usado para modificar el tamaño de la imagen, puedes usar el PhotoImage de tkinter si quieres, pero modificar la imagen no va a ser posible.